# Jquery specify result loops on specific row of dynamic table header

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, loops

I have difficulties in my projects...

I want to place the results from jquery loops into dynamic table (in specific month and year).

So first, I build the JSON and the results like this:

> https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=eb05e512b80a4995b3f6d0425b813dd9

Then I build the dynamic header from user desired filter:

[image]

```
  months = (_ePYear - _sPYear) * 12;
  months -= parseInt(_sPMonth);
  months += parseInt(_ePMonth);

  var html = '';
  var counter = 0;

  html = "<thead><tr>";
  html += "<td>Subdomain</td>";

  for(i; i <= months; i++) {
    i %= 13
    if (i == 0) {
      //do nothing
    } else {
      if (i == 1 && counter != 0) {
        _sPYear = parseInt(_sPYear)+1;
      } else {
        _sPYear = _sPYear;
      }

      html += "<td>"+_sPYear+' '+i+"</td>";

      if (counter == months) {
        break;
      }

      counter++;
    }
  }

  html += "</tr></thead>";
  $('#table-mrr-detail').append(html);
```

After that, I build body in jquery to process the results to the table:
[image]

```
  //Build Body
  var html2 = '';
  var counter2 = 0;

  months2 = (_ePYear2 - _sPYear2) * 12;
  months2 -= parseInt(_sPMonth2);
  months2 += parseInt(_ePMonth2);

  html2 += "<tbody>";

  $.each(json.data, function (i, ob) {
      var me = this;
      html2 += "<tr>";
          html2 += "<td>"+this.subdomain+"</td>";
        $.each(ob.data, function (ind, obj) {

          for(i2; i2 <= months2; i2++) {
            i2 %= 13
            if (i2 == 0) {
              //do nothing
            } else {
              if (i2 == 1 && counter2 != 0) {
                _sPYear2 = parseInt(_sPYear2)+1;
              } else {
                _sPYear2 = _sPYear2;
              }
              console.log(this.month+'='+i2);

              if (this.month == i2 && this.year == _sPYear2) {
                html2 += "<td>"+this.amount+"</td>";
              } else {
                html2 += "<td>0</td>";
              }                

              if (counter2 == months2) {
                break;
              }

              counter2++;
            }
          }
        });
      html2 += "</tr>";

  });

  html2 += "</tbody>";
  $('#table-mrr-detail').append(html2);
```

But, if you look at response in my json, the data of 'alim' subdomain have value in month 09, 10, 11 year 2017...

And... From the results above, The other subdomain is not showing anything (should show data based on json and specific header)...

Any help will appreciate...
Thanks...

## EDIT

This is my init var:

```
  var _sDate = $("input#idstartdate").val();
  var _eDate = $("input#idenddate").val();

  var _sPMonth = $("select#periodMonthStart :selected").val();
  var _sPYear = $("select#periodYearStart :selected").val();
  var _ePMonth = $("select#periodMonthEnd :selected").val();
  var _ePYear = $("select#periodYearEnd :selected").val();

  var _sPMonth2 = $("select#periodMonthStart :selected").val();
  var _sPYear2 = $("select#periodYearStart :selected").val();
  var _ePMonth2 = $("select#periodMonthEnd :selected").val();
  var _ePYear2 = $("select#periodYearEnd :selected").val();

  var _subdomain = $("input#subdomain").val();
  var months = 0;
  var months2 = 0;
  var i = parseInt(_sPMonth);
  var i2 = parseInt(_sPMonth);
```

I edited my current code from @shivaji, still no luck

[image]

Comment: issue in for loop, `i2` is not initialized (reset).

Comment: please take a look of my edited question @ShivajiVarma

Comment: can you share your html ?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/jBM4xGdp here you go @ShivajiVarma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with variable usage. You are modifying actual values, which is making your logic to fail, after a loop.

I have refactored the code to make it simple.

working code link: https://jsbin.com/fotezujupu/1/edit?html,js,output

```js
var json = {"status":"success","data":[{"subdomain":"alim","data":[{"day":15,"month":9,"year":2017,"amount":"35025.97"},{"day":31,"month":10,"year":2017,"amount":"72387.01"},{"day":"01","month":11,"year":2017,"amount":"2335.06"}]},{"subdomain":"ql8","data":[{"day":7,"month":2,"year":2017,"amount":"925827.78"}]},{"subdomain":"Fathani","data":[{"day":27,"month":1,"year":2017,"amount":"231480.00"},{"day":28,"month":2,"year":2017,"amount":"240053.33"},{"day":31,"month":3,"year":2017,"amount":"265773.33"},{"day":30,"month":4,"year":2017,"amount":"257200.00"},{"day":31,"month":5,"year":2017,"amount":"265773.33"},{"day":"03","month":6,"year":2017,"amount":"25720.00"}]},{"subdomain":"asa4","data":[{"day":4,"month":10,"year":2017,"amount":"6010.03"},{"day":30,"month":11,"year":2017,"amount":"45075.21"},{"day":31,"month":12,"year":2017,"amount":"46577.72"},{"day":31,"month":1,"year":2018,"amount":"46577.72"},{"day":28,"month":2,"year":2018,"amount":"42070.19"},{"day":31,"month":3,"year":2018,"amount":"46577.72"},{"day":30,"month":4,"year":2018,"amount":"45075.21"},{"day":31,"month":5,"year":2018,"amount":"46577.72"},{"day":30,"month":6,"year":2018,"amount":"45075.21"},{"day":31,"month":7,"year":2018,"amount":"46577.72"},{"day":31,"month":8,"year":2018,"amount":"46577.72"},{"day":"21","month":9,"year":2018,"amount":"31552.65"}]},{"subdomain":"kenvapes-bpn","data":[{"day":15,"month":4,"year":2017,"amount":"85733.33"},{"day":31,"month":5,"year":2017,"amount":"177182.22"},{"day":30,"month":6,"year":2017,"amount":"171466.67"},{"day":31,"month":7,"year":2017,"amount":"177182.22"},{"day":31,"month":8,"year":2017,"amount":"177182.22"},{"day":"12","month":9,"year":2017,"amount":"68586.67"}]},{"subdomain":"ql7","data":[{"day":12,"month":1,"year":2017,"amount":"2388000.00"}]},{"subdomain":"demo-new","data":[{"day":28,"month":5,"year":2017,"amount":"13861.16"},{"day":30,"month":6,"year":2017,"amount":"14851.24"},{"day":31,"month":7,"year":2017,"amount":"15346.28"},{"day":31,"month":8,"year":2017,"amount":"15346.28"},{"day":30,"month":9,"year":2017,"amount":"14851.24"},{"day":31,"month":10,"year":2017,"amount":"15346.28"},{"day":30,"month":11,"year":2017,"amount":"14851.24"},{"day":"31","month":12,"year":2017,"amount":"15346.28"}]},{"subdomain":"fg32","data":[{"day":15,"month":9,"year":2017,"amount":"5200.00"},{"day":31,"month":10,"year":2017,"amount":"10746.67"},{"day":30,"month":11,"year":2017,"amount":"10400.00"},{"day":31,"month":12,"year":2017,"amount":"10746.67"},{"day":31,"month":1,"year":2018,"amount":"10746.67"},{"day":28,"month":2,"year":2018,"amount":"9706.67"},{"day":31,"month":3,"year":2018,"amount":"10746.67"},{"day":"28","month":4,"year":2018,"amount":"9706.67"}]},{"subdomain":"qol11","data":[{"day":3,"month":2,"year":2017,"amount":"59900.00"},{"day":31,"month":3,"year":2017,"amount":"618966.67"},{"day":30,"month":4,"year":2017,"amount":"599000.00"},{"day":"26","month":5,"year":2017,"amount":"519133.33"}]},{"subdomain":"pyusbyonline10","data":[{"day":27,"month":1,"year":2017,"amount":"113084.56"},{"day":28,"month":2,"year":2017,"amount":"117272.88"},{"day":31,"month":3,"year":2017,"amount":"129837.83"},{"day":30,"month":4,"year":2017,"amount":"125649.51"},{"day":31,"month":5,"year":2017,"amount":"129837.83"},{"day":30,"month":6,"year":2017,"amount":"125649.51"},{"day":31,"month":7,"year":2017,"amount":"129837.83"},{"day":31,"month":8,"year":2017,"amount":"129837.83"},{"day":30,"month":9,"year":2017,"amount":"125649.51"},{"day":31,"month":10,"year":2017,"amount":"129837.83"},{"day":30,"month":11,"year":2017,"amount":"125649.51"},{"day":31,"month":12,"year":2017,"amount":"129837.83"},{"day":31,"month":1,"year":2018,"amount":"129837.83"},{"day":28,"month":2,"year":2018,"amount":"117272.88"},{"day":31,"month":3,"year":2018,"amount":"129837.83"},{"day":30,"month":4,"year":2018,"amount":"125649.51"},{"day":31,"month":5,"year":2018,"amount":"129837.83"},{"day":30,"month":6,"year":2018,"amount":"125649.51"},{"day":31,"month":7,"year":2018,"amount":"129837.83"},{"day":31,"month":8,"year":2018,"amount":"129837.83"},{"day":30,"month":9,"year":2018,"amount":"125649.51"},{"day":31,"month":10,"year":2018,"amount":"129837.83"},{"day":30,"month":11,"year":2018,"amount":"125649.51"},{"day":"24","month":12,"year":2018,"amount":"100519.61"}]},{"subdomain":"oooop","data":[{"day":11,"month":9,"year":2017,"amount":"22335.59"},{"day":"17","month":10,"year":2017,"amount":"34518.64"}]},{"subdomain":"ql15","data":[{"day":9,"month":3,"year":2017,"amount":"17572050.00"}]},{"subdomain":"pyusbyonline12","data":[{"day":21,"month":1,"year":2017,"amount":"52342.50"},{"day":28,"month":2,"year":2017,"amount":"69790.00"},{"day":31,"month":3,"year":2017,"amount":"77267.50"},{"day":30,"month":4,"year":2017,"amount":"74775.00"},{"day":31,"month":5,"year":2017,"amount":"77267.50"},{"day":30,"month":6,"year":2017,"amount":"74775.00"},{"day":31,"month":7,"year":2017,"amount":"77267.50"},{"day":31,"month":8,"year":2017,"amount":"77267.50"},{"day":30,"month":9,"year":2017,"amount":"74775.00"},{"day":31,"month":10,"year":2017,"amount":"77267.50"},{"day":30,"month":11,"year":2017,"amount":"74775.00"},{"day":"05","month":12,"year":2017,"amount":"12462.50"}]},{"subdomain":"r1","data":[{"day":4,"month":1,"year":2017,"amount":"60268.16"},{"day":28,"month":2,"year":2017,"amount":"421877.09"},{"day":31,"month":3,"year":2017,"amount":"467078.21"},{"day":30,"month":4,"year":2017,"amount":"452011.17"},{"day":31,"month":5,"year":2017,"amount":"467078.21"},{"day":"25","month":6,"year":2017,"amount":"376675.98"}]},{"subdomain":"mam","data":[{"day":25,"month":9,"year":2017,"amount":"149833.33"},{"day":"05","month":10,"year":2017,"amount":"29966.67"}]},{"subdomain":"moirea","data":[{"day":29,"month":3,"year":2017,"amount":"497253.33"},{"day":30,"month":4,"year":2017,"amount":"514400.00"},{"day":31,"month":5,"year":2017,"amount":"531546.67"},{"day":30,"month":6,"year":2017,"amount":"514400.00"},{"day":31,"month":7,"year":2017,"amount":"531546.67"},{"day":"29","month":8,"year":2017,"amount":"497253.33"}]},{"subdomain":"pswdevsby14","data":[{"day":4,"month":10,"year":2017,"amount":"5384.27"},{"day":30,"month":11,"year":2017,"amount":"40382.02"},{"day":"24","month":12,"year":2017,"amount":"32305.62"}]},{"subdomain":"ql13","data":[{"day":10,"month":3,"year":2017,"amount":"169716.67"}]},{"subdomain":"dbj2017","data":[{"day":13,"month":1,"year":2017,"amount":"186272.98"},{"day":28,"month":2,"year":2017,"amount":"401203.34"},{"day":31,"month":3,"year":2017,"amount":"444189.42"},{"day":30,"month":4,"year":2017,"amount":"429860.72"},{"day":31,"month":5,"year":2017,"amount":"444189.42"},{"day":30,"month":6,"year":2017,"amount":"429860.72"},{"day":31,"month":7,"year":2017,"amount":"444189.42"},{"day":31,"month":8,"year":2017,"amount":"444189.42"},{"day":30,"month":9,"year":2017,"amount":"429860.72"},{"day":31,"month":10,"year":2017,"amount":"444189.42"},{"day":30,"month":11,"year":2017,"amount":"429860.72"},{"day":"12","month":12,"year":2017,"amount":"171944.29"}]},{"subdomain":"oke","data":[{"day":19,"month":10,"year":2017,"amount":"31350.00"},{"day":"11","month":11,"year":2017,"amount":"18150.00"}]},{"subdomain":"Fg24","data":[{"day":21,"month":3,"year":2017,"amount":"1986157.89"}]},{"subdomain":"ide2sen","data":[{"day":24,"month":1,"year":2017,"amount":"72281.56"},{"day":28,"month":2,"year":2017,"amount":"84328.49"},{"day":31,"month":3,"year":2017,"amount":"93363.69"},{"day":30,"month":4,"year":2017,"amount":"90351.96"},{"day":31,"month":5,"year":2017,"amount":"93363.69"},{"day":"05","month":6,"year":2017,"amount":"15058.66"}]},{"subdomain":"pswdevsby15","data":[{"day":26,"month":11,"year":2017,"amount":"103826.67"},{"day":"04","month":12,"year":2017,"amount":"15973.33"}]},{"subdomain":"ql5","data":[{"day":19,"month":1,"year":2017,"amount":"4907700.00"}]},{"subdomain":"pswdevjkt2","data":[{"day":23,"month":11,"year":2017,"amount":"122513.33"},{"day":"07","month":12,"year":2017,"amount":"37286.67"}]},{"subdomain":"cvabadidjajarukunsejahtera","data":[{"day":17,"month":4,"year":2017,"amount":"86775.56"},{"day":31,"month":5,"year":2017,"amount":"158237.78"},{"day":30,"month":6,"year":2017,"amount":"153133.33"},{"day":31,"month":7,"year":2017,"amount":"158237.78"},{"day":31,"month":8,"year":2017,"amount":"158237.78"},{"day":"10","month":9,"year":2017,"amount":"51044.44"}]},{"subdomain":"ql4","data":[{"day":12,"month":1,"year":2017,"amount":"9419333.32"}]},{"subdomain":"fg31","data":[{"day":28,"month":5,"year":2017,"amount":"56218.99"},{"day":30,"month":6,"year":2017,"amount":"60234.64"},{"day":31,"month":7,"year":2017,"amount":"62242.46"},{"day":31,"month":8,"year":2017,"amount":"62242.46"},{"day":30,"month":9,"year":2017,"amount":"60234.64"},{"day":"29","month":10,"year":2017,"amount":"58226.82"}]},{"subdomain":"PT-SAM","data":[{"day":4,"month":2,"year":2017,"amount":"68586.67"},{"day":31,"month":3,"year":2017,"amount":"531546.67"},{"day":30,"month":4,"year":2017,"amount":"514400.00"},{"day":31,"month":5,"year":2017,"amount":"531546.67"},{"day":30,"month":6,"year":2017,"amount":"514400.00"},{"day":"23","month":7,"year":2017,"amount":"394373.33"}]},{"subdomain":"Redia","data":[{"day":28,"month":1,"year":2017,"amount":"240053.33"},{"day":28,"month":2,"year":2017,"amount":"240053.33"},{"day":31,"month":3,"year":2017,"amount":"265773.33"},{"day":30,"month":4,"year":2017,"amount":"257200.00"},{"day":31,"month":5,"year":2017,"amount":"265773.33"},{"day":"02","month":6,"year":2017,"amount":"17146.67"}]},{"subdomain":"lotusbogalima","data":[{"day":10,"month":3,"year":2017,"amount":"171499.59"},{"day":30,"month":4,"year":2017,"amount":"514498.78"},{"day":31,"month":5,"year":2017,"amount":"531648.74"},{"day":30,"month":6,"year":2017,"amount":"514498.78"},{"day":31,"month":7,"year":2017,"amount":"531648.74"},{"day":"02","month":8,"year":2017,"amount":"34299.92"}]},{"subdomain":"pyusbyonline11","data":[{"day":21,"month":1,"year":2017,"amount":"17900.00"},{"day":28,"month":2,"year":2017,"amount":"23866.67"},{"day":31,"month":3,"year":2017,"amount":"26423.81"},{"day":30,"month":4,"year":2017,"amount":"25571.43"},{"day":31,"month":5,"year":2017,"amount":"26423.81"},{"day":30,"month":6,"year":2017,"amount":"25571.43"},{"day":31,"month":7,"year":2017,"amount":"26423.81"},{"day":31,"month":8,"year":2017,"amount":"26423.81"},{"day":30,"month":9,"year":2017,"amount":"25571.43"},{"day":31,"month":10,"year":2017,"amount":"26423.81"},{"day":30,"month":11,"year":2017,"amount":"25571.43"},{"day":31,"month":12,"year":2017,"amount":"26423.81"},{"day":31,"month":1,"year":2018,"amount":"26423.81"},{"day":28,"month":2,"year":2018,"amount":"23866.67"},{"day":31,"month":3,"year":2018,"amount":"26423.81"},{"day":30,"month":4,"year":2018,"amount":"25571.43"},{"day":31,"month":5,"year":2018,"amount":"26423.81"},{"day":30,"month":6,"year":2018,"amount":"25571.43"},{"day":31,"month":7,"year":2018,"amount":"26423.81"},{"day":31,"month":8,"year":2018,"amount":"26423.81"},{"day":"03","month":9,"year":2018,"amount":"2557.14"}]},{"subdomain":"pswtestsurabaya2","data":[{"day":6,"month":5,"year":2017,"amount":"12183.05"},{"day":"23","month":6,"year":2017,"amount":"46701.69"}]},{"subdomain":"damarsatu","data":[{"day":0,"month":1,"year":2017,"amount":"0.00"},{"day":28,"month":2,"year":2017,"amount":"800177.78"},{"day":31,"month":3,"year":2017,"amount":"885911.11"},{"day":30,"month":4,"year":2017,"amount":"857333.33"},{"day":31,"month":5,"year":2017,"amount":"885911.11"},{"day":"30","month":6,"year":2017,"amount":"857333.33"}]}]};

// Assuming your input fields are strings, so parsing them here itself.
var _sPMonth = parseInt('1');
var _sPYear = parseInt('2017');
var _ePMonth = parseInt('11');
var _ePYear = parseInt('2017');


var noOfMonths = ((_ePYear - _sPYear) * 12) - _sPMonth + _ePMonth + 1;
  
var columns = getColumns();

$('#table-mrr-detail').append(getTableHeaderHtml(columns));

$.each(json.data, function (sdI, subdomainItem) {
  $('#table-mrr-detail').append(getRowHtml(subdomainItem));
});

function getColumns(){
  var columns = [];
  var counter = 0;
  for(var i=0; i < noOfMonths; i++) {
    var column = {};
    column.month = ((_sPMonth + i -1) % 12) + 1;
    column.year = parseInt((_sPMonth + i -1) / 12) + _sPYear;
    columns.push(column);
  }
  return columns;
}

function getTableHeaderHtml(columns){
  var  html = "<thead><tr>";
  html += "<td>Sub domain</td>";
  $.each(columns, function(index, column){
    html += "<td>"+column.year+' '+column.month+"</td>"
  });
  return html;
}

function getRowHtml(subdomainItem){
  var html = "<tr>";
  html += "<td>"+subdomainItem.subdomain+"</td>";
  $.each(columns, function(index, column){
    var obj = findByMonthAndYear(subdomainItem.data, column);
    if (obj) {
      html += "<td>"+obj.amount+"</td>";
    } else {
      html += "<td>0</td>";
    }
  });
  return html;
}

function findByMonthAndYear(data, column){
  for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (data[i].year == column.year && data[i].month == column.month) {
            return data[i];
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

  <table id="table-mrr-detail" class="table"></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: updated my answer, to fix the issue. problem is with your variable usage

Comment: with few modification, its work like a charm! thanks buddy!